# Autocomplete environment variables in bash commands (like RAILS_ENV=test bundle ...)

Tags: bash

I want to add some environment variable names and possible value to the list of completions in bash.
For an example, in Ruby on Rails, I run commands like
`RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails db:migrate`

I want to be able to type
`RAI<tab>`
> completion fills in `RAILS_ENV=`
`RAILS_ENV=te<tab>`
> completion fills in `RAILS_ENV=test`

Sometimes I can use `complete -W "my values" my_command` to attach values to a specific command, but here I do not want to attach these to a command, I want them just available, much like the list of commands themselves.

Is this possible?

Comment: equal sign is not a big problem since it's acceptable to manually input it. the difficulty is in customizing autocomplete rules for the first word.

Comment: @pynexj nah, not at all. the problem **is** the part after th equal sign

Comment: @oguzismail  just realized bash-5.0 introduced `-I` for the 1st word completion. then, after `=` we can just use the default behavior to autocomplete pathnames. so the question for OP is: what's the completion items after `=`?

Comment: @pynexj apparently they are user-defined strings rather than pathnames. And if I'm not mistaken, there is no `complete` option for specifying a compspec for assignment statements. Of course we can remove `=` from COMP_WORDBREAKS, but then, how are we supposed to restore it back after the completion is done?

Comment: @oguzismail right. actually i've removed `=` from `COMP_WORDBREAKS` in my bashrc.

Comment: @kafex  so if you can afford to remove `=` from `COMP_WORDBREAKS` then there's a solution.

Comment: @pynexj Yes, I would be very content even with manually typing in the = sign. The completion items afterwards are the different Ruby on Rails environments, things like 'test', 'development', and 'production'.  
I also am OK with removing = from COMP_WORDBREAKS.  
So, looks like using bash 5.0 (I will have to upgrade) with -I option is the solution?

Comment: @pynexj Well, I'm really intrigued then, if you post an answer I'll definitely upvote, because there still are question marks about this for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example which requires Bash `5.0+` and `=` be removed from `COMP_WORDBREAKS`.

```
# tested with bash-5.0.16

_rails()
{
    local cmd=$1 cur=$2 pre=$3
    local -a envs=()
    local i

    for i in production test-foo test-bar; do
        envs+=( "RAILS_ENV=$i" )
    done

    if [[ $cur == R* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${envs[*]}" -- "$cur" ) )
    fi
}

COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//=/}
complete -I -F _rails -o bashdefault
```

NOTE:

- It completes to `RAILS_ENV=` only if the first word starts with `R`.
- By using `-o bashdefault`, it can still autocomplete normal command names.